# Surjectivity of the integral operator

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, riemann-integration

Let $[a,b]\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be a closed interval and $\mathcal{R}[a,b]$ denote the linear space of Riemann integrable functions. It is well known that the integral operator 
$$R(f)(x):=(Rf)(a)+\int_a^xf(t)\,dt$$
maps elements of $\mathcal{R}[a,b]$ to the space of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ i.e. $R:\mathcal{R}[a,b]\to C[a,b]$. 
My questions are: Is this map surjective? If not, is there a counterexample?

Comment: I presume that you want elements of $C[a,b]$ to vanish at $a$; otherwise, the map isn't injective for an even more trivial reason---any nonzero constant function is not in the image of $R$.

Comment: @Batominovski thanks for pointing this out. Now each constant function has as preimage the identically zero function. And of course as you said if we want $R$ to be also injective we should invoke $(Rf)(a)=0$ for all $f$. Seems like the Weierstrass function as suggested by Quantic is a valid counterexample?

Comment: Opps, I meant surjective, not injective.  And yes, Quantic_Solver gave a good example, given that you shift the function to be zero at $a$.

Comment: The definition of $R(f)$ has trouble: What does $R(f)(a)$ even mean?

Comment: @zhw.  The OP wants to take the quotient of $C[a,b]$ by constant functions, but I agree that the presentation here looks confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $\mathcal{C}\big([a,b]\big)$ is taken modulo constant functions.  Any function in the image of $R$ is differentiable everywhere except on a set of Lebesgue measure $0$, but not every continuous function has this property.  A properly shifted and rescaled version of Weierstrass function as suggested by Quintic_Solver is a continuous function which is differentiable nowhere, so it does not lie in $\text{im}(R)$.

However, you can shift and rescale the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) to fit your interval $[a,b]$ to get a continuous function on $[a,b]$ that is not in the image of $R$, but the Cantor function is differentiable everywhere outside the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set), which has measure $0$.  Therefore, the condition that a function is differentiable outside a set of Lebesgue measure $0$ is also insufficient to be in $\text{im}(R)$.  Indeed, $\text{im}(R)$ consists of only (but not all) [absolutely continuous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) on $[a,b]$ vanishing at $a$ (and the Cantor function is not absolutely continuous).

Being absolutely continuous is also insufficient.  As zhw. illustrated, the function $g(x):=\sqrt{x-a}$ is absolutely continuous, but any of its [weak derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_derivative) is unbounded.  Therefore, $g'$ is not Riemann-integrable.   Every absolutely continuous function has a weak derivative.  We know that every function in $\text{im}(R)$ is absolutely continuous.  Thus, each function in $\text{im}(R)$ has a bounded weak derivative, whence [Lipschitz continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity).

To get all the image of $R$, we note that a (real- or complex-valued) function $f$ on $[a,b]$ is Riemann-integrable if and only if it is bounded and continuous outside a set of Lebesgue measure $0$.  Hence, $F\in\text{im}(R)$ iff a weak derivative $F'$ of $F$ is bounded and continuous outside a set of Lebesgue measure $0$ ($F'$ exists because $F$ is absolutely continuous).  This translates as follows: $\text{im}(R)$ consists of all functions $F$ that is Lipschitz continuous and continuously differentiable everywhere outside a set of Lebesgue measure $0$.

Comment: A step function is Riemann integrable, but its integral function won't be differentiable where the step function jumps.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to see every function in the range is Lipschitz, but there are plenty of functions in $C[a,b]$ that are not Lipschitz. For example, $g(x)=\sqrt {x-a}.$ Hence the integral operator is not surjective.

Answer (score 0):

The map isn't surjective. A counterexample is the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) which is continuous.